# How can I get the RequestBody in GlobalExceptionHandler class using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, uncaughtexceptionhandler

===============controller class==================

```
@PostMapping(path = "/products")
public ResponseEntity<ProductResponseDTO> saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product, @RequestHeader(name = "uuid", required = false) String uuid, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    request.setattribute("product",product);
    productRepo.save(product);
    ......
    .....
}
```

=======================Exception handler class==========================

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorHandler{
    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> generateRuntimeException(RuntimeException re, WebRequest request, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws IOException {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails();

            Product product=(Product)servletRequest.getAttribute("product");
            errorDetails.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
            errorDetails.setMessage("500");
            errorDetails.setDetails(re.getMessage());
            log.error("Exception occured3: " + re);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
]
```

I can see while executing the `request.getAttribute("product")`, it is showing null value.  Once the exception happens, it is not getting inside the controller body, directly passing the control to exception class. As a result, `resuest.setAttribute("product")` is not setting the value to the request.

I Googled and tried several ways but still getting null values.
Anyone please help me to get it resolved.

Comment: Please make sure the class annotated with @ControllerAdvice is scanned by spring.

Comment: @ControllerAdvice already added in the ExceptionHandler class.

Comment: please put @ComponentScan in one of your configuration class and provide the package name in which GlobalErrorHandler is present